# How to make a discord.py bot ignore commands from a user id?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot ignore a specific user from using any commands

This is my current code

```
blacklist = {userid}



@bot.command()
async def command(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in blacklist:
        return
        await ctx.send('You are blacklisted')
```

Comment: As presented, the code following the `return` is "dead": will never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong cause blacklist MUST be a list:

```
blacklist = [123, 456, 789]
```

and then as you coded.

Comment: [`in` is a *common sequence operation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations); and [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s provide it, too.